# Running fat jar vs sbt run

Tags: java, scala, reflection, sbt, uberjar

I have a scala program that runs the following piece of code.

```
1.    public static HttpCredentialProvider loadHttpCredentialProviders(String name) {
2.       ServiceLoader<HttpCredentialProvider> providers = ServiceLoader.load(HttpCredentialProvider.class, BasicAuthCredentialProvider.class.getClassLoader());
3.        Iterator var2 = providers.iterator();
4.
5.        HttpCredentialProvider provider;
6.        do {
7.            if (!var2.hasNext()) {
8.                throw new ConfigException("HttpCredentialProvider not found for " + name);
9.            }
10.
11.           provider = (HttpCredentialProvider)var2.next();
12.       } while(!provider.getScheme().equalsIgnoreCase(name));
13.
14.       return provider;
15.   }
```

I will create an uber/fat jar using `sbt assembly`. Then I will use the command `java -jar app.jar`. The result is the following exception

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: HttpCredentialProvider not found for BASIC
    at io.confluent.security.auth.client.provider.BuiltInAuthProviders.loadHttpCredentialProviders(BuiltInAuthProviders.java:56)
    at io.confluent.security.auth.client.rest.RestClient.<init>(RestClient.java:117)
    at io.confluent.security.auth.client.rest.RestClient.<init>(RestClient.java:95)
    at io.confluent.kafka.clients.plugins.auth.token.TokenUserLoginCallbackHandler.configure(TokenUserLoginCallbackHandler.java:67)
    at io.confluent.kafka.clients.plugins.auth.token.AbstractTokenLoginCallbackHandler.configure(AbstractTokenLoginCallbackHandler.java:86)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.LoginManager.<init>(LoginManager.java:60)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.LoginManager.acquireLoginManager(LoginManager.java:105)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:161)
```

The above error is thrown from `line 8`.

I will execute `sbt run` and I see no error. The application runs perfectly fine.

Things I tried:

1. Since the difference is `sbt run` and `java -jar` perhaps the jar does not contain relevant classes (BasicAuthCredentialProvider). I validated that `jar -tf` infact does have the classes present. If the class was not present I would suspect a ClassNotFound exception.
2. Remote debug both modes of running the application using `JAVA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005" sbt run` and `java -jar -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005 app.jar`. I idea was to find out what could be actually happening. I got some interesting results here. I stepped through the code and saw that this line

```
ServiceLoader<HttpCredentialProvider> providers = ServiceLoader.load(HttpCredentialProvider.class, BasicAuthCredentialProvider.class.getClassLoader());
```

calls the `ServiceLoader.load` which working with some reflection

```
public static <S> ServiceLoader<S> load(Class<S> service,
                                            ClassLoader loader)
{
    return new ServiceLoader<>(Reflection.getCallerClass(), service, loader);
}
```

This is where I am exactly blocked. I want to keeo understanding what is causing the issue but I am not sure how to debug through reflection issues (if that what the problem is). When running `sbt run` the code executes another function that exists in the same class the above code exists. This function is called `loadBasicAuthCredentialProvider`. However, that function never gets called by `java -jar`. This tells me that the reflection is playing some role here.

3. I also switched JAVA version from 8 to 11. No Bueno there either.

If anybody has other ideas I could try to debug this issue it would be great!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! The fix was in the merge strategy for assembly. It looked like this:

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case _ => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

We need to make sure META-INF was added for services. So it needs to look like this.

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", "services", xs@_*) =>
    MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList("META-INF", xs@_*) =>
    MergeStrategy.discard
  case x =>
    MergeStrategy.first
}
```

I found the answer through [KAFKA-8340](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-8340)!

> Observe that the services loaded by that invocation **do not include** the
> ones described in the META-INF/services/... file contained in the JAR
> in the plugin's directory